# Как забиндить Dictionary<String, Int32[]> ключом к ListBox, а значениями выбранного элемента к ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть словарь вида `Dictionary <String, Int32[]> someDict`. Ключи биндятся к `ListBox.ItemSource`, а вот значения выбранного ключа должны биндиться к `ComboBox.ItemSource`. Как это сделать, не могу понять.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=someDict.Keys}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=comboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Comment: Через конвертер?

Comment: Но вообще-то, `Dictionary` не выглядит как хорошая вьюмодельная структура данных. Где семантика? Вы наверняка хотите `ObservableCollection<Entry>`, где `Entry` содержит имя и список.

Comment: @VladD А иначе никак? В моем случае будет проще сделать пару строчек в окне, чем пилить новый конвертер. На счет создания еще одного класса и хранения его списка вместо словаря я уже думал, но хочется так попробовать пока.

Comment: Никак. У вас `ListBox` биндится только к ключам, значит, информация о значениях теряется.

Comment: Хм, я по ходу был не прав, таки можно. Если биндиться не к ключам, а к самому словарю.

Comment: @VladD Все ошибаются :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас все вроде правильно, только вместо

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=comboBox  ....
```

надо

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.Value}"/>
```

У меня это выглядит так:

```
<ListBox Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lb, Path=SelectedItem.Value}"/>
```

Здесь `DataContext` у вьюшки напрямую поставлен в словарь. В Вашем случае,  в `ListBox` `ItemsSource` вместо `{Binding}` ,будет `{Binding someDict}`

---

Но я бы лучше сделал обертку над словарем

Comment: Так-же ответ мне дали на [английском stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988377/binding-dictionarystring-int32-by-keys-to-listbox-and-selected-item-values-to).  
На счет сделать обертку я уже подумал, этот вариант все таки более правильным будет. Точнее я просто метод хранения информации изменю. Будет класс хранящий String и Int32[], ну и список этого класса.

Comment: Binding ElementName=comboBox Это у меня просто опечатка, допущенная при редактировании для копирования кода сюда.